# Is there any benefit to creating multiple consoles in GameDevStory?

Tags: game-dev-story

I have created 17 games or so on my first console (64 bit chip, BD disc, console) and it has 30% of the market share. It had 33% but some other consoles have been released.

Could I produce games on this console indefinitly? Would creating, say, a "sequel" for my console be have any benefit since my current configuration is already the most expensive of each option.

I am not sure if there's a dynamic of "gamers are getting bored of this generation consoles" or not. I do know that consoles you make never go off the market.

But I don't want to waste a year and a half and piss off my impatient fans if it offers no advantage or benefit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your console will never go out of date so you can make games on it forever.  Once you've picked the best options for your console, there's really not much benefit of making another one unless you want to try for more market share.  Usually, there isn't enough time in the game (the portion that affects your max score), to make 2 great consoles as you pointed out that you'll lose some fans during the long development time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going for an all-time best for the 20-year capital high score, then I would not recommend making a second console.

However, there are higher level parts you can use for your console than what is initially shown.

If you have 4 hardware engineers on staff, you'll be able to utilize the 'Potato Chip' CPU at a cost of $90 million. If you have 6 on staff, you'll be able to use 'Punch Cards' as your media at a cost of $94 million.

It seems that the benefits of these extra parts do not outweigh the extra cost, but I haven't tested it heavily.